# Throws "No embeddedresource found for NameSpace.App" on iOS but not on Android

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

I'm building a cross-platform application but in iOS, no matter what I try it always throws an `XamlParseException` in the `App.Xaml.g.cs` thus preventing me to moving forward on my iOS development

I've tried searching for possible solution about my problem but none of them works. I already checked if the `x:Class` on the `App.xaml` and `.csproj` contents are correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Bump... deleted the `bin` and `obj` folder in all solutions then `Build all` fixed my problem